# PDO mysql_real_escape_string how to use within prepared statment

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to escape a string that I am putting into a statement.

I know PDO prepares and executes, (for those that do not know PDO prepares a statement to stop any extra commands from being ran, so the statement knows what it is running before variating data is injected, thus removing the possibility of being injected) my trouble at this time is that I want to run a statement with a variable which is apart of the MySQL rule (see below).

```
$sql = $this->PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM `weight` WHERE `user_id`=:id ORDER BY $order $direction");
```

As you can see I am using custom order by and ASC/DESC the statment above works, but I do not feel it is secure enough. putting the direction as a switch statement is easy enough but for the point of future expansion I would like to escape the $order rather than using a switch or hard coded array.

I have used mysql_real_escape_string in many ways on $order but the statement does not like it, any ideas? EDIT ---- Full code of function below, no guess work really needed..

```
public function getWeightByUserOrderBy($id, $order, $direction) {
$order1 = $PDO->quote($order);
    $sql = $this->PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM `weight` WHERE `user_id`=:id ORDER BY $order1 $direction");
    $sql->execute(array(
        ":id" => $id
    ));
    $sql = $sql->fetchall();
    return $sql;
}
```

Comment: *"I have used mysql_real_escape_string in many ways on $order but the statement does not like it"* - **Answer:** That's because MyQL doesn't like it when you intermix APIs. Use one API type only. Show full code and read up on how [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) work.

Comment: If you have full control over what's put into your query there's no scope for injection. The contents of `$order` and `$direction` should be validated against a whitelist and only _your_ values used. You don't need to use `real_escape_string()` at all, particularly from a different & deprecated API.

Comment: To add to @MikeW's comment, you cannot escape `$order` ever, not using `mysql_real_escape_string` and not using PDO specific escape functions. Escape functions only work on values and not on column names. So if the value of `$order` is user-provided, you always need a hard-coded array - a whitelist - to check against. The array could be filled querying the database for the column names of course...

Comment: @jeroen - Thank you for the useful insight I did not know this. I shall find other alternatives, I will say rather than assuming I know nothing about PDO and telling me to read up on it you told me a straight fact and saved me a lot of time. I shall just have to tailor my code and developers. thank you.

Comment: @user35453 Note that this has nothing to do with PDO, it applies to any set of database functions, mysql, mysqi, PDO, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to use `mysql_real_escape_string`, from a deprecated interface.

For `$direction`, verify that it contains `DESC` or `DESCENDING`. Otherwise set it to empty string, or `ASC`.

If `$order` is supposed to contain an identifier (a column name), then you could escape it using backticks, and remove any backticks within the variable, e.g.

```
  ... ORDER BY `".str_replace("`","",$order)."` $direction
```

If `$order` contains an expression, that's a bit trickier.

Comment: *"You wouldn't want to use `mysql_real_escape_string`, from a deprecated interface."* - OP is using PDO (least from posted 1 line of code); it really boils down to that those two APIs don't intermix, as I stated in a comment under OP's question. OP should be posting full code to avoid all the guesswork.